# Sleeptime only works in intervals of 15

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

my logitech LUA script used to work flawlessly, but for some reason now i can only adjust "sleeptime" by increments of 15 instead of 1. i used to be able to adjust sleeptime up and down by 1, but now the speed doesn't change unless i adjust 15 times. what am i missing?

```
sleeptime=15

function OnEvent(event, arg)

EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 7 and IsModifierPressed("lshift")) then  

sleeptime = sleeptime - 1

end

if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 7 and IsModifierPressed("ctrl")) then   

sleeptime = sleeptime + 1

end     

if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 7 and IsModifierPressed("alt")) then 

sleeptime = 15

end

if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsMouseButtonPressed(3)) then  

repeat

Sleep(sleeptime)

MoveMouseRelative(3, 3)

Sleep(5)

MoveMouseRelative(-3, 3)

until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)

end

end
```

Comment: Sometimes `Sleep(sleeptime)` sleeps until the beginning of a time slice (Windows time slice is about 15 ms) instead of the exact amount of milliseconds.  This effect might be seen or not seen depending on the CPU load.  The 15 ms precision is the best you can reliably get from `Sleep()`

Comment: So, the advice: make `sleeptime` constant (10) and change the `y` distance (second argument of `MoveMouseRelative`).

Comment: i'm not super well versed in LUA, it took me forever just to get this script "working" lol is there a way to make the y axis adjustable up and down like the sleeptime in my script? i tried making a local variable but didn't seem to work for me

Answer (score 0):

```
local vertical_speed = 3.0

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 7 then  
      if IsModifierPressed("lshift") then 
         vertical_speed = vertical_speed * 1.05   -- increase speed
      elseif IsModifierPressed("ctrl") then
         vertical_speed = vertical_speed / 1.05   -- decrease speed
      else IsModifierPressed("alt") 
         vertical_speed = 3.0
      end
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then  
      local frac, x, y = 0, 1
      repeat
         Sleep(15)
         x, y, frac = -x, math.modf(frac + vertical_speed)
         MoveMouseRelative(x * 3, y)
      until x > 0 and not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
   end
end
```